# What is "Exponent Value" in this table of Bluetooth Characteristic Format Types?

Tags: bluetooth

This table purports to list the various data types you might find in a Bluetooth message: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/format-types

The last column in the table is titled "Exponent Value" and takes only the values Yes or No. There is no explanation offered, and I can't relate this to anything else in the table. The "Yes" values are all associated with integer types (but other integer types are "No"). All the floating point values are "No".

Anybody know what they're trying to tell us? It appears you can't get any support unless you work for a company that is a member of the Bluetooth SIG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the answer to this question in the [Core Specification version 4.2](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=441541) (Vol 3 / Part G / 3.3.3.5.3)

It says the following:

The exponent field is used with integer data types to determine how the value is further formatted. The exponent field is only used on integer format types as indicated in the format field in Table. The exponent field is a signed integer.

actual value = Characteristic Value * 10Exponent

As can be seen in the above equation, the actual value is a combination of the Characteristic Value and the value 10 to the power Exponent. This is sometimes known as a fixed point number.

For example, if the Exponent is 2 and the Characteristic Value is 23, the actual
value would be 2300.

For example, if the Exponent is -3 and the Characteristic Value is 3892, the
actual value would be 3.892.